# Domain of GW Enterprise account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-workspace

I have a very basic question related to GW Enterprise accounts.

The enterprise accounts are tied with a consumer domain.

Do the domain of the google docs URL change as per the consumer domain?

For e.g. if I take example.com as a domain for my account.

Will the URL of my google document be docs.google.com/document/d/ or example.com/document/d/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They stay on the `docs.google.com/` domain.

I have a GW Enterprise Plus account and all Google documents no matter of type stay on the Google domain.

Think about it: how would your documents be able to be set up on your domain without changing your DNS records?

Quick and dirty proof (with my domain removed but you can see that I'm logged into my `.xyz` Workspace account):

#### From Sheets UI:

[image]

#### From Admin Console:

[image]

Comment: Please refrain from answering off-topic questions; we don't want to encourage them.